# VB (macro in excel) - compile error

Tags: vba

i am try to create an uploader in excel using vb (macro) to store data in an access database. i believe in terms of the script everything is ok. its just that when i run the upload it gives me the error Compile error - User-Defined type not defined and once i click on OK it highlights the part where it finds the error which is:

```
Private Sub Upload_Click() <------ this part!!!! 
Dim cs As ADODB.Connection 
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset 
Dim ServerName As String 
Dim DatabaseName As String 
Dim TableName As String 
Dim UserID As String 
Dim Password As String
```

can anybody help me make this work....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the reference `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.0 Library`'

Menu Item: `Tools/References`

Comment: where do i need to add these Microsoft Activex Data Objects 2.0 library? 

Sorry im really a bit new to this thats why im seeking help..

Comment: yes i checked that but the references is greyed out.. its not clickable.. 
what does this mean?

Comment: There's an outline of a Check-mark next to my answer.  Click this check-mark and it should turn green.  Thanks!